# Set PyQt QLabel to display peerAddress after connected to a server

Tags: python, network-programming, pyqt4

I try to make simple operation in PyQt4. After a client connects to a server I want to change a text in a label to show an address of the server.

```
def connectToServer(self):
    self.connectButton.setEnabled(False)
    self.socket.connectToHost(HOST, PORT)
    print(self.socket.peerAddress())
    try:
        self.lblSrvConnected.setText(self.socket.peerAddress()) # changes lbl to address
    except:
        self.lblSrvConnected.setText('Some error')
```

The print statement gives `<PyQt4.QtNetwork.QHostAddress object at 0x02C23DB0>` and the label always changes to `Some error` from `expect`. I tried to do conversion to string with `str()`, use `peerAddress` without bracket etc. When I call `peerName()` instead of `peerAddress()` it prints `localhost` but `peerPort()` gives `0` instead of the port I use.

I expect I have two problems.

First, I can't get out address and port from peerAddress. I tried assign it to variables but then have an error: `TypeError: QHostAddress' object is not iterable`

Second, I expect, I try to change the label before connection is established. I tried with `.waitForConnected()` but can't make it that way either.

I can't find how to make it working.

Comment: Why didn't you look at the docs for [peerAddress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#peerAddress) and [QHostAddress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhostaddress.html), instead of just trying things randomly?

Comment: The problem is that I did and it should be straight forward but I still have an error. This is why I try different ways (not random)

Comment: `print(self.socket.peerAddress().toString())`

Comment: @ekhumoro it gives blank line. I try exactly as you suggest. There is not output. Also if I assign it to a variable: `myPeer = self.socket.peerAddress().toString()` and `print(type(myPeer), len(myPeer))` the output is `<class 'str'> 0` The client connects because I see it on the server's side. Servers shows me new connection and prints me a port from which it was done. if I close the GUI server shows the client was disconnected.

Comment: I thought you already understood that the address will be null until the connection has been established (which obviously happens asynchronously). So you will need to update the labels in a slot connected to the socket's [connected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#connected) signal.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> **QHostAddress.toString (self)**
>
> Returns the address as a string.
>
> For example, if the address is the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1, the
>   returned string is "127.0.0.1". For IPv6 the string format will follow
>   the RFC5952 recommendation.

from documentation QT4

Comment: It gives me errror. 
`.peerAddress.toString()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'toString'`